# How can I create gesture based transitions with react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I've tried searching everywhere but the only thing I can find that is remotely similar to what I want to do is the `PanResponder`. However, with `PanResponder` I will have to make custom headers which I am not sure is the right way of doing this.

To be specific, I want to add the ability for the user to swipe to transition to a new screen/route in a **Stack Navigator.**

If it can't be done, then I'd like to know if making a custom header is ok?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: were you able to find any solution for the same?